# Arraylist of byte[] Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, byte

I'm wondering if it is possible for me to add multiple byte[] of a file into an arraylist
and later on write the btye[] inside back to a file.

Sorry for being vague, this is my first time posting
below is a segment of my code.
the output file seem to be bigger then the original file and i cant seem to figure out why

```
ArrayList<byte[]> tempStorage = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
byte[] byteArray;

while (n < length && n != -1)
{
    byteArray = new byte[960];
    n = in.read(byteArray, 0, 960);
    tempStorage.add(byteArray);
    count++;
}

for (byte[] temp: tempStorage) {
    fileOuputStream.write(temp);
}
fileOuputStream.close();
```

Comment: why don't you try and see it yourself?

Comment: Please try before you ask, but if you have a problem on your test, you can ask!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say that size of your array is `4` and size of file is `6`. You read first 4 bytes, place it in array and store that array in list. Then you are reading that last 2 bytes (since size was 6) and store it in array which size is 4. This means that some part of that last array will be empty *and should be ignored*.

But in your

```
for (byte[] temp: tempStorage) {
    fileOuputStream.write(temp);
}
```

you are writing last array entirely, including part which should be ignored (so you will write 4 bytes instead of 2 which will make your file bigger).

So for *last* temp you should use `write` method which will describe how many bytes from that array we want to use (you have that information in `n` variable since you get it in `n = in.read(byteArray, 0, 960);`).

So for last `temp` try something more like [`fileOuputStream.write(temp,0,n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-)